# Re-stream rtsp ip cameras for milestone

Tags: camera, bridge, rtsp

I have 15 axis ip cameras and i’m using milestone essentials which only allows 8 devises so i’m looking to use a raspberry pi that will take the axis cameras and restream them into rtsp streams

I’m thinking i can use the 16 channel driver in in milestone and add the one devise with all of the feeds

Sort of like this raspberry pi wyze bridge that goes out and gets all of the cameras and converts the camera feeds to rtsp

I would be eternally grateful for any help from anyone